# OAuth 2: Should the state expire?

Tags: oauth-2.0

For services which use a `state` parameter for the OAuth protocol, the client can maintain state between between steps 1 and 3 of the procotol:

1. The user is redirected from the client to the service with a `state`
2. The user consent to the scopes
3. The user is redirected back to the client with the authorization code and the `state`

Is there any good reason to set a maximum to the delay between step 1 and 3? That would concretely be implemented by setting an expiration date to the `state`. It seems reasonable that the OAuth 2 flow should complete rather rapidly (for example, it would be very weird to reach step 3 one year after step 1), so I'm tempted to add an expiration date of about 1 day to the `state`. Is there any security or functionnal best practice regarding this? If no, is there any explicit drawback of expirying the state?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `state` is a recommended parameter in the authorization request, not a required parameter. So it may not be included at all.

The `state` parameter is an opaque value used by the client to maintain state between the request and callback. The parameter is recommended to prevent CSRF attacks, see [section 10.12 of the Oauth2 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.12).

I've never seen an expiry set for the state. A user could navigate to the client, get redirected to the authorization server and hibernate the machine on the login screen. When the user wakes up the machine, they could complete the sign on and get redirected back to the client. If the client still knows about the state, I don't see why this should fail, even if it's days later.

The issued authorization code on the other hand does have a limited lifetime. Once issued, it should be used within a few minutes and can only be used once.